# makefile not running .PHONY target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

when i am trying to run the following makefile its not running the .PHONY target, does anyone knows why?

````
node_modules: package.json
   npm install

.PHONY: puppeteer-deps
puppeteer-deps:
   sudo apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 lib    gtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca    -certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget```
````

Answer (score 2):

Make only tries to build targets that it needs to, to satisfy the goal.  Targets that aren't needed to create the goal are not run.  Making the target `.PHONY` does not change this fact: it only says that *if* a target needs to be built *and* it's marked `.PHONY`, then it will always be built.

In make, the goal is either the targets given to make on its command line or, if no targets were given on the command line, the first target in the makefile.

Here if you run `make` your goal is `node_modules` and since neither that target nor any of that target's prerequisites list `puppeteer-deps` as a prerequisite, it won't be built.

Consider if you had a `clean` target, marked `.PHONY`... you sure wouldn't want that target to always be run!